# no image with rails in production?

Tags: css, image, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, assets

I have some classic image png in app/assets/images/...

but in production, after

```
rake assets:precompile
```

images not appear! If I inspect CSS source, I can see

```
.logo {
    background-image: url("/assets/logos/logo.png");
  ... }
```

it's the same code in my css file.

But I observer during precompile assets :

```
 /var/www/demos/public/assets/logos/logo-741199bb95821c02bca7c68ca66ff5f5.png
```

So why rails not modify automaticly the name of link with added hash?

if I open a new tab with direct path :

```
http://domain.com/assets/logos/logo-741199bb95821c02bca7c68ca66ff5f5.png
```

it's works...

So how I missed to do this automatic link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good answer is:

use in CSS.SCSS :

```
asset-url('relative/path/image.png')
```

use in views :

```
<%= image_path('relative/path/image.png') %>
```

or `image_tag` method to generate  tag with automatic good path

Comment: Note that your "css" needs to actually be a "scss" file for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set [asset path in css, or scss](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass).

Try `background-image: image-url("logos/logo.png")`, or `background-image: asset-url("logos/logo.png", image)`